# Could not load file or assembly PInvoke

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, breeze, asp.net-core-3.0

I am converting a BreezeJS application to run on .NET Core and Linux.  I got to the point where I am trying to save my changes in my WebAPI Service and I am getting the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.PInvoke, Version=4.0.0.0'

The last called breeze method is called IsFrameworkAssembly.  I found the .Net Core version of this method here: [IsFrameworkAssembly](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/9983caa343b2f42e098836399b27ceca9ff935c0/AspNetCore/Breeze.Persistence/BreezeConfig.cs#L96-L108).  It makes a call to `GetCustomAttributes` which then goes into the system code.

**I am not sure what is going wrong here.  Is `GetCustomAttributes` not supported in .Net Core?  Is this a bug in .Net Core?  Or is there something else going on here?**

---

In case it is important here is the full call stack:

```
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(QCallModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(MetadataToken caCtorToken, MetadataImport& scope, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1& derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at Breeze.Persistence.BreezeConfig.IsFrameworkAssembly(Assembly assembly)
   at Breeze.Persistence.BreezeConfig.c.b__5_0(Assembly a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator`1.ToList()
   at Breeze.Persistence.BreezeConfig.get_ProbeAssemblies()
   at Breeze.Persistence.BreezeConfig.get_Instance()
   at Breeze.Persistence.PersistenceManager.CreateJsonSerializer()
   at Breeze.Persistence.PersistenceManager.InitializeSaveState(JObject saveBundle)
   at Breeze.Persistence.PersistenceManager.SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle, TransactionSettings transactionSettings)
   at MyService.DataAccess.SaveChanges(JObject saveJObject) 
   at MyService.Controllers.MainController.SaveChanges(JObject saveJObject) 
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```